# Transformation of random variable

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am looking to recreate a derivation of a PDF using a transform of random variables. I did the original derivation in Mathematica with the Mathstatica package, but when I updated Mathematica recently my Mathstatica installation no-longer works and I am getting no response from Mathstatica support.

Thus, I want to try and do the same thing in plain Mathematica, but am not having any luck.

Here is my Mathematica + Mathstatica code

```
(* Define our Gaussian distribution *)
f = 1/(\[Sigma] Sqrt[2 \[Pi]])
    Exp[-((x - vergMean)^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))];   

(* Domain and assumptions *)
domain[f] = {x, 0, 
    Pi/2}   && {vergMean \[Element] Reals, \[Sigma] \[Element] 
     Reals, \[Sigma] > 0, h > 0, Re[h] != 0};

(* Transformation of random variables *)
g = Transform[y == h/Tan[x], f]
```

This gives the result

```
(E^(-((vergMean - ArcCot[y/h])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))) h)/(Sqrt[
 2 \[Pi]] (h^2 + y^2) \[Sigma])
```

I am assuming that I should be able to use `TransformDistribution` to do the same, but I cannot get it to work at all.

For example,

```
(* Define our Gaussian distribution *)
f = 1/(\[Sigma] Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) Exp[-((x - vergMean)^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))];

(* Transformation of random variables *)
transF = 
 TransformedDistribution[y = h/Tan[x], x \[Distributed] f,
  Assumptions -> {vergMean \[Element] Reals, \[Sigma] \[Element] 
     Reals, \[Sigma] > 0, h > 0, Re[h] != 0, x > 0, x < Pi/2}]

PDF[transF, x]
```

This code doesn't work and just outputs a duplicate of the original code.

I think I am probably doing something dumb / missing something obvious, but I cannot see what it is.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: The correct syntax would be: ```f = NormalDistribution[vergMean, σ];
transF = TransformedDistribution[h/Tan[x], x \[Distributed] f, 
   Assumptions -> Element[vergMean, Reals] && σ > 0 && h > 0];
PDF[transF, x]``` , but unfortunately Mathematica isn't able to find the PDF.

Comment: *mathStatica* is a great.  But it does assume that you determine that the function is one-to-one to be able to use its `Transform` function.  The chapter on transformations is excellent and states "As per Theorem 1, Transform and TransformExtremum should only be used on transformations that are one-to-one."  And it even tells you what to do when the transformation is not one-to-one.

Comment: @JimB, thanks. Yes, the it is clear the function has a one-to-one mapping. I am really hoping that I can get Mathstatica up and running again. Updating Mathematica caused some issues and after initial contact via support, I am having trouble getting hold of them. From what they said it is a simple fix as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### EDIT

It seems to work now. The key is to use the `TruncatedDistribution` so $h \cot(x)$ is monotonic.

```
transF=TransformedDistribution[h Cot[x],
  x\[Distributed]TruncatedDistribution[{0,π/2},NormalDistribution[μ,σ]],
  Assumptions->μ∈Reals&&σ>0&&h>0];
FullSimplify[PDF[transF,y],{y>0,h>0,μ∈Reals,σ>0}]
```

gives

```
(E^(-((μ + 2 ArcTan[(y - Sqrt[h^2 + y^2])/h])^2/(2 σ^2))) h Sqrt[2/π])/((h^2 + y^2) σ *
  (Erf[μ/(Sqrt[2] σ)] - Erf[(-(π/2) + μ)/(Sqrt[2] σ)]))
```

which is similar to what you had before but properly normalized.

### Original

I've been trying to coax Mathematica into doing this but it is still refusing. As a workaround, you can use the definition of a transformed distribution directly. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar)

$$
f_Y(y) =f_X\big(g^{-1}(y)\big)  \left| \frac{d}{dy} \big(g^{-1}(y)\big) \right|
$$

Which Mathematica actually handles fine

```
f=Exp[-((#-μ)^2/(2 σ^2))]/(σ Sqrt[2 π])&;
g=h Cot[#]&;
gi=Quiet@InverseFunction[g];
Simplify[f[gi[y]]Abs[D[gi[y],y]],{y>0,h>0}]
```

gives

```
(E^(-((μ-ArcCot[y/h])^2/(2 σ^2))) h)/(Sqrt[2 π] (h^2+y^2) σ)
```

as desired.

I know that's not ideal, but at least it's a way forward. Still a bit surprised `TransformedDistribution` with `Assumptions` or `TruncatedDistribution` can't seem to handle it.

Comment: Is $(0,\pi/2)$ associated with $x$ or $y$?  That resulting pdf for $y$ doesn't integrate to 1 over $(0,\pi/2)$ or $(0,\infty)$.  For that transformation formula to work, the function needs to be monotonic but only if $x$ is restricted to say $(0,\pi/2)$ or say $(0,\pi)$).   I probably haven't had enough coffee this morning so I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Ah, that's fantastic. Yes, by definition the domain of x is (0, Pi/2). In reality for the physical problem it will never get near the the limits. But, geometrically that is the case. I was also surprise vanilla Mathematica could not handle it. Even when putting in all assumptions possible. How would the code need to be adjusted in light of the limits of x? Many thanks again.

Comment: I seem to remember the integral working with Mathematica + Mathstatica, but I can currently not run that code to check.

Comment: I didn't do any sanity checks since OP gave the desired result in the question. That said, it should be $0<x<\pi/2$ which restricts $y>0$. I have updated the `Simplify` line to reflect this. Indeed the resulting PDF doesn't integrate to 1 because of the restriction of $0<x<\pi/2$ which makes the original distribution a `TruncatedDistribution` which itself does not integrate to 1 (they're only considering a slice of the full normal distribution).

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I am being a bit slow today. You are correct, the distribution over x is truncated, so the integral will not be 1. I think the etiquette is to give others a chance to answer prior to accepting. But this seems to replicate the behaviour of Mathstatica. Thankyou.

Comment: @bRost03:  I think your original statement about a truncated distribution was right on the money. If you first start with the truncated normal and specify a numeric value for $h$, then one gets a result. Trying different values for $h$ shows a distinct pattern.

Comment: @flyingmind If it’s a pdf, it must integrate to 1.

Comment: @JimB - I don't know what I was doing this morning! I could have sworn I tried the `TruncatedDistribution` and it didn't work, but now it is haha. I must have flipped the order of the arguments or something equally silly.

Comment: Join the club. I wish that would stop happening to me.

Comment: Thanks both. I will need to think about this a bit more. I think Mathstatica was probably doing a lot of this thinking for me. The theoretical problem is geometrical and has no limits as such, but the actual problem has physical limits. However, the limits all depend about how the brain represents physical quantities i.e. can the brain represent a negative distance, or negative ocular convergence angle? Ping me a message if you are interested and I can explain a bit more. And thank you again for your help and insights.

Comment: @flyingmind can't DM on this site, but feel free to ask another question if you want more help!

Answer (score 4):

Amplifying on answer by @bRost03

```
distX = TruncatedDistribution[{0, Pi/2}, NormalDistribution[μ, σ]];

distY = TransformedDistribution[h/Tan[x], x \[Distributed] distX, 
   Assumptions -> h > 0];

g = Assuming[{y > 0, h > 0, σ > 0, μ ∈ Reals},
  PDF[distY, y] // FullSimplify]

(* (E^(-((μ + 2 ArcTan[(y - Sqrt[h^2 + y^2])/h])^2/(
  2 σ^2))) h Sqrt[2/π])/((h^2 + 
   y^2) σ (Erf[μ/(Sqrt[2] σ)] - 
   Erf[(-(π/2) + μ)/(Sqrt[2] σ)])) *)
```

Verifying that total probability is unity

```
Assuming[{h > 0, σ > 0, μ ∈ Reals},
 Integrate[g, {y, 0, Infinity}]]

(* 1 *)

Plot3D[g /. {μ -> 0, σ -> 1}, {y, 0, 5}, {h, 0, 5},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {y, h, PDF}),
 PlotRange -> {0, 1},
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

```
G = Assuming[
  {y > 0, h > 0, σ > 0, μ ∈ Reals},
  CDF[distY, y] // FullSimplify]

(Erf[(π - 2 μ)/(2 Sqrt[2] σ)] + 
 Erf[(μ + 2 ArcTan[(y - Sqrt[h^2 + y^2])/h])/(Sqrt[2] σ)])/(
Erf[μ/(Sqrt[2] σ)] - Erf[(-(π/2) + μ)/(Sqrt[2] σ)])

Limit[G, y -> Infinity]

(* 1 *)

Plot3D[G /. {μ -> 0, σ -> 1}, {y, 0, 20}, {h, 0, 5},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {y, h, CDF}),
 PlotRange -> {0, 1},
 WorkingPrecision -> 15,
 MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is really great. I should have thought about using TruncatedDistribution. I've been using Mathematica for a few years now, but have barely scratched the surface of what it is capable of.